# How does the travel works in One Piece universe?

Tags: one-piece

I have noticed that traveling between and within the oceans in the One Piece world isn't easy. 
[image]

However, the Marines and some advanced pirate crews/alliances commute daily between the oceans. To be more specific, here are a few examples to demonstrate what I mean:

1. The Marines travels between every oceans they want. By using Seastone on their ships, they can easily travel through the Calm Belt and switch between the Grand Line/New World and all Blues. Because the Marines is a member of the World Government, they can also pass the Red Line via Mary Joa.

   However, the Seastone technique (Episode 410) is a new invention from Dr. Vegapunk. How did the Marines travel through the Calm Belt so easy before that? Another example in [episode 502-503](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiFOvnqltYw): How did a World Government ship travel from the Grand Line to East Blue 10 years ago when Seastone technique hadn't been invented?
2. In [Luffy's past](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhK3BRBsF34), Shanks was in the East Blue, then in the [Battle of Marine Ford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD-4E3Zg_Qs), he was again in Grand Line, etc.

   Same for Whitebeard. One time, Whitebead was in the Grand Line, [then](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_v1KGYYf6Y) in the East Blue, and then again in the Grand Line, etc.

   How do Shanks and Whitebeard manage to travel between the Grand Line and the Blues on daily basis? **Do Whitebead, Shanks and other Pirates also use Seastone like the Marines?**
3. And what about Monkey D. Dragon? [One time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXfNIwcfa_M), Dragon was in the East Blue. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ZCploiduQ), he was again in the Grand Line.

So I hope you see what my question is. I'm especially curious about the daily switching between the Grand Line/New World and Blues. As I know, the only way to enter the Grand Line is via the Reverse Mountain, which isn't the most harmless way as you can see in [episode 61](http://onepiece-tube.com/folge/61). Does that mean that every time Whitebeard and Shanks want to go to the Grand Line, they have to pass this small river with their gigantic ships?

Apart from getting to the Grand Line, how do they leave the Grand Line/New World? According to the [maps](http://www.opwiki.de/images/Karte_der_Grandline.jpg), there is no way to get out. How did [Krieg](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Krieg) leave the Grand Line?

Comment: This is overall kind of broad. In one question, you're asking how the government was able to travel as they pleased before the Seastone technique from vegapunk. Another question you're asking is specifically how krieg was able to make it back across the Grand Line. Another is if certain pirates like Whitebeard and Shanks use seastone like the marines do... The list goes on, but basically there's too many questions here. I'm voting to close as too broad, try to find breakpoints so you can ask **one** specific question. Then, if you have additional questions, post them as additional questions.

Answer (score 8):

It's been revealed there are several ways to travel apart from traditional ships.  It's also been hinted that the islands range from prehistoric to scifi advanced, so there are methods yet to be revealed.

1. For example, Rayleigh swam from the Grand Line through the Calm Belt to reach the Amazon's Island.
2. Skypieans have been shown to have flying devices and shells that could propel.
3. Amazons have been shown to use creatures to pull the boats.
4. Blackbeard's boat is just a giant raft, implying they just use a sail and row. (Given the strength of the characters in this class, chances are that there were a lot of rowing involved)
5. Franky came up with Coup de Burst, which also lets them cross vast distances quickly.
6. Several subs have been shown so far including Wapol, and the Heart Pirates indicating travel without need for waves. The Marines probably have access to this tech (at least, Z's Neo Marines did).
7. More importantly, several fruits aid in propulsion. Ace used fire to power his skateboat.  Whitebeard could probably just cause waves even in the Calm Belt to propel his ships (and quite fast I might add, based on wave size and speed).  Dragon (though not confirmed how) was the reason for the gust of wind that helped Straw Hats escape from Loguetown. He may be using similar methods. Dragon also used to have Bartholomew Kuma, who can repel things and land them anywhere in the world.
8. Several characters, including Sanji, can use Moonwalk.

Comment: I'm sure there's more devices, ships and fruits I'm missing on this list. Feel free to add to it.

Comment: the standard pedel boats. And as shown in some episodes is that people with haki can make the see kings go away. Franky invented a peddel boat upgrade for their ship, technically rowing is never out of the question, there are more ships who could probably been rown.

Comment: i remember that some ships function with a motor but no clue if it is the one that uses seastone