# How big would the One Piece planet/universe be if looked from outer space?

Tags: one-piece

Since I don't read the manga and I can't remember a lot of it, maybe someone who has more extensive knowledge/understanding of One Piece world can have a rough estimate of how big the universe/planet/ocean is, I'm just curious because all that sea and island being wide apart and we haven't even got to half (or quarter) of it (I guess?).

Would the One Piece planet look similar to earth's size? Or is it more comparable to Jupiter, for example?

Comment: Could this question be simplified to: how big physically is the planet in *One Piece* universe?

Comment: What makes you think that One Piece happens on a planet?!

Comment: i think the answer just gonna be a guess, as most of the character are related to real people, the one piece world is similar to earth

Comment: Considering there are some (unofficial) maps like on [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20679/) or [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22385/), probably it's possible to guesstimate the answer if there are known scales for any known distances traveled...

Comment: You aren't gonna get a specific answer unless you're fine with relying on calcs, and some headcanon assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

The One Piece planet is similar to Earth not only in its Earth-inspired character names. In [Chapter 115](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_115), Vivi mentions the "Age of Dinosaurs" on Little Garden and Kuzan (Aokiji) has a move called [Ice Age](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hie_Hie_no_Mi), suggesting that there was an Ice Age on this planet. With the exception of the Grand Line, most of the planet experiences four seasons, regular tides, and weather patterns similar to Earth. All of this in addition to regular days and nights suggest that the One Piece galaxy is heliocentric.

However, the One Piece planet has [6 moons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB27B.png), and one of these moons has its own moon (which is large enough itself to be a self-gravitating sphere). Assuming the Ohara citizens were correct about their model of the planet and that the One Piece universe has the same laws of physics as ours, their planet is probably not Earth. Theoretically, it should be much larger but considering imaginary logic, maybe we should just leave the physics up to our imaginations.

I would put the One Piece planet at a similar size to Earth's for several reasons:

1. According to the [One Piece Timeline](https://thelibraryofohara.com/the-one-piece-timeline/) (not perfect but probably the best we can get with what we have), it took Luffy and his crew something like 75 days to get through [Paradise](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise) with excursions (again, I understand that could be spot on or way off, we just can't know for certain). Earth has a circumference of ~40,000 km. The average caravel (Going Merry) speed is let's say 5 knots with a Nami navigator and Grand Line conditions. A Franky-built brig (Thousand Sunny) averages let's say 10 knots because Franky is awesome and Nami is navigating. So that means the Straw Hats traveled [Paradise](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise) at an overall average of let's say 7 knots. 20,000 km / 7 knots is ~65 days without excursions and the Straw Hats knock out most of these excursions in a day or two.
2. Apart from the Grand Line, the One Piece planet has Earth-like weather patterns and four seasons per year. Considering Luffy supposedly has a Gregorian calendar birthday ([Cinco de Mayo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy)), there are 365 days in said years. Oh, also, he weighs [64 kg](https://www.absoluteanime.com/one_piece/luffy) and that's a reasonable Earth weight. He is really strong though so maybe it's a bit smaller and that's why everyone can jump really high and Luffy only weighs 64kg, apart from "because reasons," which is probably how we should be approaching this question. Now, correct me if I'm wrong but I do not believe either of these measurements are technically canon, so take all that with the same grain of salt with which you are probably taking this question and answer.
3. The deepest part of the ocean we know about in One Piece is just below Fishman Island, which lies [10km](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_490) below sea level. Not-so-coincidentally, the deepest depth of Earth's ocean is [just over 10km](https://geology.com/records/deepest-part-of-the-ocean.shtml). Since the One Piece planet supports land and water on its crust similarly to Earth, it probably has a similar geological structure to Earth. With identical water depths, I think I can rest my case here.

Answer (score 2):

I stopped last year reading the manga in the Big Mom flashback, so I don't know if it has been answered in the manga or not, but, in Robin flashback in chapter 392 (episode 275), there's a planetarium of One Piece planet with the moons.

There are 5 orbits, with 6 or more satellites. There might be another moon(s) behind the planet, so from that, we can say that One Piece planet might be very big than planet Earth. It might be like Saturn or even Jupiter size.

We can also see the Grand Line coming from almost the top to the bottom of the planet and the rest are just islands. Unlike our planet, there are big lands which are the continents, but in One Piece planet, the only big land is the Red Line.

Here's a picture of that planetarium:

[image: Planetarium on chapter 392/episode 275]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that most of One Piece (Straw Hats adventures) were on the little part that is named Grandline, so don't forget about the Four Seas. They may have bigger islands. Look at their size (East Blue, West Blue, South Blue, North Blue).

[image]

So, can you take it into consideration?

Add another fact that Kuma can repel things at the speed of light, and imagine that with that speed, it took Luffy 3 days and nights to reach Amazon Lily while in a repel bubble that travels at the speed of light.

I say this because the Four Seas are not explored properly. So, don't base One Piece on Grandline. That is hardly a tiny light of One Piece, about 10% of the entire world, and it got about thousands of islands (Grandline alone), not to mention the ones in the Four Seas.

Comment: Where does this map come from? Can you provide a source?

Comment: "Kuma can repel things at speed of light", source definitely needed here (i.e. an exact chapter, not just "One Piece"). 3 days at the (real-world) speed of light makes over a hundred BILLION kilometers so - assuming that your speed-of-light argument holds - this means either 1) they flew in the repel bubble several times around the world and this does not help answering the question or 2) the world is so big that it would take hundreds of lives to accomplish the kind of trips drawn and described in One Piece.

Answer (score -1):

As mirroroftruth [mentioned](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/how-big-would-the-one-piece-planet-universe-be-if-looked-from-outer-space#comment60976_46799), One Piece is based on real life: most characters are based on real historical people and many places as well. For example:

- Dressrosa = Spain
- Wano = Japan
- Kurohige = Edward Teach (even the name is the same)

However, it seems to me that islands are not very big so I wouldn't say the One Piece world is as big as the Earth...

Comment: Just because some of the characters are "based off" of other characters doesn't necessarily mean that it's similar in size.  In fact in some ways it is most definitely different from the earth geographically, such as only having 1 continent, which spans the circumference of the planet.