# One piece world travel

Tags: one-piece

How does one travel across different blues in one piece?

Consider this for example:

A person from north blue wishes to go

1: West blue- but that means he will have to cross calm belt and then grand line (new world) perpendicular to the current and then again calm belt. I understand that navy does it with its special seastone ships but how does normal people or traders do it?

2: east or south blue: if you travel through north blue, you will reach red line ( reverse mountain), which will launch you into grand line (Paradise). Again you are surrounded by calm belts, how do you get out?

Or

You travel the other side and reach Mary Geoise. But that point will again be surrounded by calm belt, being the passing point between 2 halves of grand line. So you cannot reach it, unless you are actually on the grand line(paradise side). Also, the grand line has a current to it, which means you cann not enter the paradise half ( east-south grand line) from.new world ( north-west grand line).

Thanks, hope I am clear with the question. :)

Comment: You basically answered your question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the travel works in One Piece universe?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20679/how-does-the-travel-works-in-one-piece-universe)

Comment: @Gagantous that question is closed as too broad, so that’s not useful to close this as a dupe as.

Answer (score 1):

If you read how the reverse mountain works, you will find out that the top of the mountain has 4 paths towards the surrounding seas and 1 path that gets you to the Grand Line.

I made a aproximate map of the OP world here [OP MAP](https://ibb.co/9q3jMf8) some time ago and I had studied quite alot about how the world is connected in One Piece.

Good question anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question. Travel in one piece is very difficult. You have to cross the calm belt from the North blue to get to the West blue. This is unattainable by most people in the One Piece world, however there are a handful of people who can. Such as, Big News Morgans has a ship that can fly and the Marines have a ship that is able to cross the calm belt.